# Calculations on Subquery in strong typed dataset

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, subquery, strongly-typed-dataset

following background: i have a Table-valued Function that returns a Table that is a kind of filtered view(views can not be parameterised) on a large table. Now i need many row count values on different conditions. Is it possible to get all count values in one query without having to query this function for every condition?

For the sake of completeness(it doesnt really matter, you may read over it), this is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[getRuleConfigBySetSlsRules] (
 @fiRuleSet AS TinyInt,
 @fiServiceLocations AS NVARCHAR(4000),
 @fiRules AS NVARCHAR(400)
)

RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN  (
 SELECT     ruleChangeTo.fiSet, ruleChangeTo.fiClaimStatus, ruleChangeTo.fiRule, ruleChangeTo.fiSL, ruleChangeTo.fiResult, 
                      dimClaimStatus.ClaimStatusName AS OldStatus, dimClaimStatus_1.ClaimStatusName AS NewStatus, locSL.SLName, ruleSet.SetName, 
                      ruleResult.ResultName, locMarketUnit.MarketUnitName, locCountry.CountryName, ruleRule.RuleKey, ruleRule.RuleName, ruleRule.RuleDescription, 
                      locGSP.WCMSName AS GSP_WCMSName, locGSP.Active AS GSP_Active, locGSP.WCMSKeyNumber AS GSP_WCMSKeyNumber, 
                      locSL.Active AS SL_Active, locSL.WCMSName AS SL_WCMSName, locSL.WCMSKeyNumber AS SL_WCMSKeyNumber, locSL.fiSLType, 
                      locSLType.SLTypeName, ruleChangeTo.fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo
FROM         locGSP INNER JOIN
                      locCountry ON locGSP.fiCountry = locCountry.idCountry INNER JOIN
                      locMarketUnit ON locCountry.fiMarketUnit = locMarketUnit.idMarketUnit INNER JOIN
                      locSL ON locGSP.idGSP = locSL.fiGSP INNER JOIN
                      ruleChangeTo ON locSL.idSL = ruleChangeTo.fiSL INNER JOIN
                      dimClaimStatus ON ruleChangeTo.fiClaimStatus = dimClaimStatus.idClaimStatus INNER JOIN
                      ruleResult ON ruleChangeTo.fiResult = ruleResult.idResult INNER JOIN
                      ruleRule ON ruleChangeTo.fiRule = ruleRule.idRule INNER JOIN
                      ruleSet ON ruleChangeTo.fiSet = ruleSet.idSet INNER JOIN
                      locSLType ON locSL.fiSLType = locSLType.idSLType INNER JOIN
                      dimClaimStatus AS dimClaimStatus_1 ON ruleChangeTo.fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = dimClaimStatus_1.idClaimStatus  INNER JOIN
                       dbo.Split(@fiServiceLocations, ',') AS ServiceLocations ON ServiceLocations.Item = ruleChangeTo.fiSL INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Split(@fiRules, ',') AS Rules ON ruleChangeTo.fiRule = Rules.Item
WHERE (ruleChangeTo.fiSet = @fiRuleSet)
)
```

And in the following way i can get one count-value, but in fact i need 30 conditions on the same query(the WHERE-clause).

[image]

What is the best way to accomplish this in a strong typed dataset without one query for every value? I dont catch that.
This is the query that must be extended(out of the above image)with various status-conditions and their count values:

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) AS CountValidReject
FROM         dbo.getRuleConfigBySetSlsRules(@fiSet, @ServiceLocations, @Rules) AS RuleConfigFilter
WHERE     (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8)
```

To come to the point: do i need a stored-procedure with a temp-table or something like that or can i create and query a temp table in this sql in the Dataset? I don't want to call *getRuleConfigBySetSlsRules* for every value.

Thanks

**EDIT**:
This is the final query which returns 1 row with many count-values as columns. Thanks to Steve again for the CASE WHEN hint. Its very efficient.

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesApprovedInvalid,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesApprovedReject,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesApprovedReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesEscalatedInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesEscalatedReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesEscalatedReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesEscalatedValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 8) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesRejectInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 8) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesRejectValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesReviewInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesReviewReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesReviewValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 5) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesValidApproved, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesValidInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesValidReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleAppliesValidReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotApprovedInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotApprovedReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotApprovedReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotEscalatedInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotEscalatedReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotEscalatedReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotEscalatedValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 8) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotRejectInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 8) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotRejectValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotReviewInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotReviewReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotReviewValid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 5) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotValidApproved, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 2) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotValidInvalid, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotValidReject, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS RuleApplNotValidReview, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllValidApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 1) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllValidNotApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllApprovedApplies,          
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 5) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllApprovedNotApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllReviewApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllReviewNotApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllRejectApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 7) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllRejectNotApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllEscalatedApplies, 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiResult = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus = 9) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AllEscalatedNotApplies
FROM         dbo.getRuleConfigBySlsRules(@ServiceLocations, @Rules) AS RuleConfig
WHERE     (fiSet = @fiSet)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help a lot if you were more specific and gave an example. I'm not sure what "30 conditions on the same query(the WHERE-clause)" means or what "strongly typed" has to do with anything. Can you give two or three example of the 30 things you want?

A guess at what you want is something like this:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiClaimStatus = 1) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8)
        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS myCount1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiClaimStatus = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 8)
        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS myCount2,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN (fiClaimStatus = 2) AND (fiClaimStatus_ChangeTo = 6)
        THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS myCount1,
  ...
FROM dbo.getRuleConfigBySetSlsRules(@fiSet, @ServiceLocations, @Rules) AS T
```

If this isn't close to what you need, please provide more information.

Comment: I will have a look at it on monday, but when it works then it is what i was looking for. Btw, your examples are fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any way around it. Put the results of your table-valued function into a temp table and then run your aggregation queries off of that.